# How to prove this sequence converges to 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

How can we prove this converges to 1?

$a_n = \sqrt[n]{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[i]{i} }} $

It is upper bounded by 1 because $ \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}} < 1$ and $\sqrt[n]{n}$ converges to 1 but that's all I have.

Comment: What’s the use of $i$?

Comment: What is the initial value of $i$?

Comment: It is also lower-bounded by $1$ by just taking a single term of the sum!

Comment: It was a mistake, $i$ was supposed to be inside the sum instead of n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that for $x\ge1$, $e^{-1/e}\le x^{-1/x}\le1$. Thus,
$$
\left(ne^{-1/e}\right)^{1/n}\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^ni^{-1/i}\right)^{1/n}\le n^{1/n}
$$

Comment: Thanks for this, looks concise but I'm not good with analysis. How can we show that?

Comment: Find the maximum of $\frac{\log(x)}x$

Comment: ohhh, thanks, now I understand the other solution better too! Thanks for this, marking as answer for that reason

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the sequence $n^{1/n}$ is eventually decreasing. Indeed, the function $x^{1/x}$, with $x\geq 1$, can be written as $e^{\frac 1x \log x}$, and taking the derivative we see
$$
(x^{1/x})' = x^{1/x} ( -\frac {1}{x^2} \log x + \frac{1}{x^2} ) =  x^{1/x} \frac{1}{x^2} (1 - \log x) < 0, \ \text{ if }  x\geq 3.
$$
Hence, we get
$$
 (n-2) \frac{1}{3^{1/3}}  \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^{1/i}} \leq n.
$$
Taking the $1/n$-th root on the last expression, we get that $a_n \to 1$ as the $1/n$-th power of both sides of the above inequality converges to $1$.

Comment: How does the lower bound come up? The -2 is to ignore the first 2 terms? Also, how does the bound of 3 come up? Did we round up to the closest integer for the root of lnx=1?

Comment: we showed that $x^{1/x}$ is decreasing when $x\geq 3$, hence $ 3^{1/3} \geq i^{1/i} $ for all $i =3,4,..., n$. It follows that $\frac{1}{3^{1/3}} \leq \frac{1}{i^{1/i}}$ when $i\geq 3$, and summing this over $n-2$ terms when $i=3,...,n$ we get the lower bound.